# What is the meaning of the suffix '-ory' (laboratory, conservatory)?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

I am interested in the the meaning which the suffix '-ory' contributes to words like laboratory, conservatory and lavatory.

I often find if difficult to research prefixes and suffixes, so would be grateful of some input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix is ***[-ory](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ory#etymonline_v_36281)*** meaning *pertaining to, serving for*;often added to words of Latin origin, but used with other words also:

> adjective and noun suffix, "having to do with, characterized by, tending to, place for," from Middle English -orie, from Old North French -ory, -orie (Old French -oir, -oire), from Latin -orius, -oria, -orium.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. So 'purgatory' and 'refectory' share the same 'residence of the agent or instrument' meaning.